# Position matrix representation in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, superposition

For quantum harmonic oscillator, if wave function is in a superposition of two wave functions,
$$
\psi(x)=(1/\sqrt2)\psi_n(x)+(1/\sqrt2)\psi_m(x)
$$
and position operator is represented as a matrix, for $n=0, m=1$:
$$
<\psi|x_{ij}|\psi>=x_{01}= 1
$$
My question is, what if the wave function is a superposition of 3 wave function, do I just apply $<\psi|x_{ij}|\psi>$? where $\psi$ is a superposition of three wave functions?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have written down your matrix elements ambiguously. Recall
$$
 |\psi\rangle= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|m\rangle  +|n\rangle), \\
x_{mn}= \langle m|\hat x |n\rangle= \langle m|( a^\dagger + a )|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1} ~\delta_{m,n+1}+ \sqrt{n} ~\delta_{m,n-1}.
$$

It is then evident that $\langle \psi|\hat x|\psi \rangle = (x_{10}+x_{01})/2=1$,
for your specific state. A state consisting of three or 137, for that matter, oscillator eigenstates (number states), would be evaluated the same way,
$$
\langle \psi|\left (\sum_{m,n} |m\rangle x_{mn}\langle n|\right ) |\psi\rangle .
$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what your $x_{ij}$ is about but of course when you want to compute the expectation value of $x$ (or in principle any operator) you can do $\langle \psi|x|\psi\rangle$